# how to vary a function being used to implement different types of analysis in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to give my users the option of varying the type of analysis in an app and so I must vary the function being used... This is not as straight forward as it sounds... 
There are different layout algorithms in igraph r-package each implemented in a command such as: "layout.fruchterman.reingold", "layout.drl", "layout_with_kk" etc.

I would like to somehow be able to let my users choose the command to implement what ever algorithm they like within the following code:

```
shinyUI(plotOutput("graph"))


serveractual <- function(input, output) {
output$graph<-renderPlot({
    adj_mat<-adjacency(adj)
    g <- simplify(graph.adjacency(adj_mat, mode='directed', weighted=TRUE,  add.colnames=NA))
    coords_fr = layout.fruchterman.reingold(g, weights=E(g)$weight)
    plot.igraph(g, layout=coords_fr, vertex.label=NA)
  })
}
shinyApp(uiactual, server actual)
```

At first I tried:

```
selectInput(inputId = "adj", "choose graph type", choices=c("layout.fruchterman.reingold", "layout.drl", "layout_with_kk")),

coords_fr = input$adj(g, weights=E(g)$weight)
```

but of course parameter variation doesn't work that way.

So how do I implement "selectInput" to vary the function being used for analysis??
Any tips?

PS. you can define the "adj" object (adjacency matrix) in your local R environment in order to run the shiny app with the following code:

```
set.seed(1)

# generate a couple clusters
nodes_per_cluster <- 30
n <- 10

nvals <- nodes_per_cluster * n

# cluster 1 (increasing) 
cluster1 <- matrix(rep((1:n)/4, nodes_per_cluster) + 
                   rnorm(nvals, sd=1),
                   nrow=nodes_per_cluster, byrow=TRUE)

# cluster 2 (decreasing)
cluster2 <- matrix(rep((n:1)/4, nodes_per_cluster) + 
                   rnorm(nvals, sd=1),
                   nrow=nodes_per_cluster, byrow=TRUE)

# noise cluster
noise <- matrix(sample(1:2, nvals, replace=TRUE) +
                rnorm(nvals, sd=1.5),
                nrow=nodes_per_cluster, byrow=TRUE)

dat <- rbind(cluster1, cluster2, noise)
colnames(dat) <- paste0('n', 1:n)
rownames(dat) <- c(paste0('cluster1_', 1:nodes_per_cluster), 
                   paste0('cluster2_', 1:nodes_per_cluster),
                   paste0('noise_',    1:nodes_per_cluster))

adj<-dat
```

Answer (score 0):

sorted it with the following:

```
ui.R
radioButtons("type", "Distribution type:",
                 c("Normal" = "norm",
                   "Reingold" = "r",
                   "DRL" = "drl",
                   "Lay out with KK" = "layout"), selected = "Reingold")
server.R
data <- reactive({
    layout_style <- switch(input$type,
                   norm = layout.norm,
                   r = layout.fruchterman.reingold,
                   drl = layout.drl,
                   layout=lay_with_kk)
  })
coords_fr = data()(g, weights=E(g)$weight)
```